# Prove $\dim(\Im(g \circ f)) \leq \min\{ \dim( \Im g), \dim( \Im f) \}$ and $\dim( \ker( g \circ f ) ) \geq \dim( \ker f)$

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

For the finite-dimensional vector spaces $U,$ $V$ and $W$ with $f: U \to V$ and $g: V \to W$ show the following:

1. $\dim( \Im (g \circ f)) \leq \min \{ \dim ( \Im g), \dim (\Im f)\}.$
2. $\dim( \ker (g \circ f)) \geq \dim (\ker f).$

I am aware of a possible proof to 1. by using the rank-nullity theorem but I am unsure on how to apply that result here though.

For 2., I got $\dim( \ker(g \circ f) = \dim V − \dim  (g \circ f)(V) \geq \dim V − \dim g(V) = \dim (\ker g),$ but I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: It should be obvious that $\Im(g \circ f) \subset \Im(g)$ and also note that $(g \circ f)(U) = g(\Im f),$ by the rank-nullity, $\dim \Im f = \dim \Im h  + \dim \ker h \geq \dim \Im h = \dim (g \circ f)(U),$ where $h$ is the _restriction_ of $g$ on $\Im f.$

Comment: The part 2. is super easy, note simply that $\ker f \subset \ker (g \circ f).$

Comment: @WillM. why is it obvious that $\Im(g \circ f) \subset \Im(g)$

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathrm{Im}(g \circ f)$ and what is the definition of $\mathrm{Im}(g)$? I am pretty sure once you write the definitions and stare at them long enough you will see it is obvious.

Comment: Maybe you will need to write the image space of a linear transformation $u$ as the set of vectors $u(x)$ as $x$ runs across the domain of $u.$